# C++ Accept Any Struct In Parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I'm new in C++ and I would like to know if we can accept any struct as our method parameter.

This is the case:
I have one class (let's say `hw_manager`) that interact with the hardware class (let's say `hw_device1`). Currently `hw_manager` will call the method of `hw_device1` and the result of the method will be returned via the struct parameter (send the struct parameter as reference, and change the value of the referenced parameter).

In C++ code should be like this:

```
struct sSensorStatus {
    unsigned char sensor1;
    unsigned char sensor2;
};

bool checkSensorStatus(struct sSensorStatus &status) {
    // Change the status here
}
```

Now, since the hardware is changed, I need to create a new class, let's say `hw_device2` which has totally different operation.

```
struct sHardwareStatus {
    unsigned char loader;
    unsigned char transport;
    unsigned char ejector;
    unsigned char mouth;
};

bool checkHardwareStatus(struct sHardwareStatus &status) {
    // Change the status here
}
```

Rather than changing the code in `hw_manager` (that will affect the code above this layer) I'm planning to implement an interface, let's say `IHardware` that has `doAction` method. 
The idea is like this:

```
bool doAction(int cmdID, ????) {
    // switch case cmdID
    // based on the cmdID, type cast the ???? into the struct
}
```

What should I put in **????** to accept any kind of struct? Can I do this in C++?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Inside the hardware, I will also have another struct, so I don't think using template will be appropriate. Sorry for late clarification.

Comment: Templates. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: What about inheritance?

Comment: @user1615903 why? This is what polymorphism is all about.

Comment: his use of any kind of struct is misleading i guess. according to his requirements inheritance is the way to go. according to his **"to accept any kind of struct? "** templates is the way

Comment: @Koushik I think he didn't know what he needs :). He doesn't need to accept any struct i think

Comment: @stardust_ precisely:-)

Comment: @user1615903 I cannot use template, since in the same class, there will be more than 1 struct

Comment: @stardust_ The way that the current code return the value (in this example status) is using the struct that passed by reference. Can you suggest better way if I have new hardware with different struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use Inheritance. 
some thing like that well be in place:

```
struct HardwareStatusInterface{};
struct sHardwareStatus : public HardwareStatusInterface
 {
    unsigned char loader;
    unsigned char transport;
    unsigned char ejector;
    unsigned char mouth;
};
struct sSensorStatus : publc HardwareStatusInterface
 {
    unsigned char sensor1;
    unsigned char sensor2;
};
```

and the function:

```
bool doAction(int cmdID, HardwareStatusInterface &HI) {
    // switch case cmdID
    // based on the cmdID, type cast the ???? into the struct
}
```

Comment: instead of the empty class `HardwareStatusInterface` you could make it Purely ABS with `doAction()`?now when you inherit each derived class can give its own definition to `doAction()`. that is what the OP also desires.

Comment: I think this is the most probable way.. But how to cast the struct to the specific struct type in `doAction`?

Comment: @Ruly use cast - (SomeStruct)HI. you should really look up Koushik comment.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use polymorphism. Create a basic class for all devices and pass a pointer or reference to it as argument to the method `doAction`.

EDIT(thanks to Koushik's comment to elyashiv`s answer):

Actually a way better solution is to make the method doAction a virtual method in the base class for all devices and not pass anything at all to it.

Comment: It seems that the structures are very different and not related, inheritance makes no sense in this case.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I believe OP did not show the actual structures. All we have is `I have one class (let's say hw_manager) that interact with the hardware class (let's say hw_device1)` and then `Now, since the hardware is changed, I need to create a new class, let's say hw_device2 which has totally different operation.` Seems to me both of these are devices and it does make sense to use polymorphism.

Comment: It's the part about "totally different operation" that speaks to me speaks against using inheritance. Also I would argue that using the phrase "polymorphism" isn't correct since there really isn't any behavior or data that is common can be "polymorphised" so to say. It's just that you use a common base class to group structures that may (or may not) be related.

Comment: There are (at least) two types of polymorphism.  Run time polymorphism, and compile time polymorphism.  I'm inclined to default toward compile time polymorphism, unless run time polymorphism is deemed necessary.  I currently cannot see anything in the question that makes me deems it so.

Comment: @Ivaylo Strandjev Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Rult Google `polymorphism c++` and tons of results will show. Also have a look at elyashiv`s answer that shows what I mean. Without having the actual definitions of the structures I don't think I will be able to produce better code. And please notice Koushik's comment that is very valuable.

Answer (score 2):

you could do this :

```
struct IHardware{virtual doAction() = 0;}
```

now inherit that in

```
struct sHardwareStatus : public IHardware
{/*implementation with implementation for doAction()*/
    unsigned char loader;
    unsigned char transport;
     unsigned char ejector;
    unsigned char mouth;
     /*provide concrete definition for bool doAction() here*/
}
```

also for

```
srtuct sSensorStatus : public IHardware
{/*implementation with implementation for doAction()*/
    unsigned char sensor1;
    unsigned char sensor2;
    /*provide concrete definition for bool doAction() here*/
}
```

now when you have a new hardware inherit from the interface and then write the struct for that class. i guess `doAction()` will be different for each Hardware.

Comment: +1 Best solution in my opinion. I am sorry I kind of "stole" your idea but I didn't notice you have already added an answer.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev There is NO stealing when it comes to knowledge:-) i like to call it sharing :-) cheers.

Comment: Almost get the point but the `doAction` is called not based on the struct, instead, the `doAction` method will store the result in the struct passed to it, so I would like to put it in the `hw_device1` and `hw_device2` and the interface for both, but not in the struct. Or I have the wrong idea?

Comment: the compiler will generate doAction as so `doAction(Ihardware * const this)`internally. so what ever you want to do to the struct will remain there. the  struct can then be used in `hw_device1` and `hw_device2` as you desire.

Comment: also you where asking about casting which leads me to suggest you to look at `dynamic_cast<>`. this is particularly useful for inheritance based casting.

Comment: @Koushik Thanks a lot for the help, but the struct (for example sSensorStatus) will only be used in `hw_device1` and not `hw_device2`, because it's tightly coupled to `hw_device1`, is it still OK with this approach?

Comment: quick question. will `struct sSensorStatus` appear as a **member** of `hw_device1` only? here `struct sSensorStatus` is independant of `hw_device1` which means you can use this approach.the reason why i am suggesting this is because doAction will have to be differently coded for different hardware. hence let each hardware define its own doAction()?

Comment: @Koushik Yes, `hw_device2` will NOT use `struct sSensorStatus`. And about the `dynamic_cast<>`, apparently I cannot type cast from a parent struct to the derived struct..

Comment: you can avoid all this casting by the above method right? no business of casting involved

Comment: OK, I'll think about this first. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have just a few number of structures and functions to call, you could use templates and template specialization:

```
template<typename T>
bool doAction(T& s)
{
    return false;
}

template<>
bool doAction(sSensorStatus& status)
{
    return checkSensorStatus(status);
}

template<>
bool doAction(sHardwareStatus& status)
{
    return checkHardwareStatus(status);
}
```

As you see you don't really need the `cmdID` flag, the compiler will figure it out by itself by using the structure type alone.

Comment: Why templates in this case? Seems like polymorphism is a way better option here.